# Asus M509D advertised 8 Gigs of RAM but Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10 showing significantly less

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, memory

I saw less than 6 Gigs in Windows so I tried `free -h` command in Ubuntu and am wondering why it shows

```
nobu@nobu-gold:~$ free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        6097804     4869236      125552      161416     1103016      791532
Swap:       2097148      221856     1875292
nobu@nobu-gold:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          5.8Gi       4.7Gi       147Mi       165Mi       969Mi       682Mi
Swap:         2.0Gi       252Mi       1.8Gi
```

5.8 Gigs is significantly less than the advertised 8 Gigs.  The 147Mi under the free column also worries me.

I did not get a very good explanation from the tech at Staples who told me it's applications and the OS taking that space but isn't the Total column showing what is physically available?

Comment: What does Windows Task Manager, Memory section say about Memory usage. Perhaps edit your question and add a screen shot of Task Manager, Memory.

Comment: The "missing" ram is probably being reserved for use by the GPU.

Comment: Asus MD509D - Graphics adapter AMD Radeon RX Vega 3 - 2048 MB. This is where memory gets lost.